MySQL is throwing too many columns error when UNION two views
Okay so I am working on a client project and they have two views (view A and view B) that has 1029 columns each. Now they wanted me to create another master view to UNION ALL both View A and View B (since the views are identical so union can be performed). Now when you query view A (1029 columns) and view B (1029 columns) individually, it just loads fine.
However, when I do a union of both view A + view B then it does not work and gives error: too many columns.
Since it is a union so the combined master view still has 1029 columns only, but what I am still failing to understand is why does it work when I do a select command on View A or View B (having 1029 columns each) producing no errors but when I do a UNION on ViewA + ViewB, then it gives too many columns error? (the union result is of 1029 columns too)
Note: The create union view query (ViewX) ran successfully and the error that I am getting is received when I run any command after the view creation.
The query:
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ViewX AS
SELECT [viewA.Column AS Column1] FROM ViewA
UNION ALL
SELECT [viewB.Column AS Column1] FROM ViewB;

SELECT ID FROM ViewX LIMIT 1
And then I got this Error 1117: Too many columns
Extra:
The logic for joining tables to create ViewA is as follows:
CREATE VIEW `ViewA` AS
select
 ec.ID AS ec_ID,
 pcl.ID AS pcl_ID
 ... (1029 columns)

from
  (
    (
      (
        (
          (
            `table1` `cp`
            left join `table2` `pla` on ((`cp`.`ID` = `pla`.`PaymentID`))
          )
          left join `table3` `pc` on ((`cp`.`ID` = `pc`.`PaymentID`))
        )
        left join `table4` `pcl` on ((`pc`.`ID` = `pcl`.`ClaimID`))
      )
      left join `table5` `cla` on ((`pc`.`ID` = `cla`.`ClaimID`))
    )
    left join `table6` `pcla` on ((`pcl`.`ID` = `pcla`.`LineID`))
  )


If ViewA having 1029 columns is not returning any errors, and same
with ViewB, then why does ViewX with 1029 columns is giving too many
columns error???

Update: As per @Barmar suggestion, if I remove the CREATE VIEW AS statement and just run the plain query, it works. But I don't know why though.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3972/error-code-1117-too-many-columns-mysql-column-limit-on-table

No @EatenbyaGrue this does not answers my question. My question is rather: "If ViewA having 1029 columns is not returning any errors, and same with ViewB, then why does ViewX with 1029 columns is giving too many columns error"?

@AbhaySalvi maybe you hit a bug, since I couldn't find anything on the docs regarding a restriction on the number of columns used in UNION/UNION ALL

@AbhaySalvi - I realize it doesn't answer your question, just thought it might be useful. You may have a good reason for views with 1000+ columns but 99 times out of 100 it's the wrong approach.

@EatenbyaGrue Thanks for helping! And indeed it's bonkers, and not something that I created as it is someone else DB that I gotta work on. A client requirement basically....

Mysql often materialises union queries via temp table, therefore table related column limitations may kick in. These restrictions may not apply to a view just performing a select.

Can you elaborate more on this or refer to me an article? Because I am creating a view too from UNION command... Thanks @Shadow

Wild guess: "SELECT *" does not guarantee the order in which the columns are reported. You should select the columns individually (though that's quite a pain in the a... with 1029 columns).

Check https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54481/determining-what-algorithm-mysql-view-is-using

@RobertKock I'm pretty sure SELECT * is guaranteed to use the order that the columns are specified in the table/view definition. If you have two tables with identical schemas you can do INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2 and reliably depend on the columns matching up.

@Barmar My bad for providing the wrong query, I just checked again. I am really sorry. I didn't did SELECT * but what I did was "SELECT ec.ID AS ec_ID", then I had to manually paste for all the 1029 columns for the UNION

Can you please query SELECT @@version, @@default_tmp_storage_engine; and tell us the result?

@BillKarwin 8.0.31-google, InnoDB

Do you get this error if you try to run the query normally, rather than defining a view?

If you SET default_tmp_storage_engine=MyISAM; and then query the view, does it still cause the error? I'm trying to test if your view is simply exceeding the InnoDB limit of 1017 columns as it creates a temp table.

@Barmar I do not get the error any longer if I just run the query instead of creating a view for it! Very interesting thing. Do you know why is this happening?

You may also need to SET internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine=MyISAM;

@BillKarwin Does it has any repercussions? As the DB is in production and I am a bit scared of any consequences. Can we change pre-existing table engine to MyISAM and if I want to go back to InnoDB then can I do that again?

First, I don't recommend testing anything in production. Do it on a development or staging server. Second, the table that would change is only a temporary table created by the query, and only in the session in which you change the options I mentioned (i.e. don't use SET GLOBAL).

I would be careful with that setting, since it affects all CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE statements. The documentation doesn't say anything about it being used for subtables created automatically while processing queries.

No, I don't know how to fix it. I'm just trying to narrow down the circumstances, this will be helpful when you file the bug report.

@Barmar So you mean this is a bug? Because SELECT command runs fine but when I use CREATE VIEW it gives "too many columns" error. I have already reported it to MySQL bug report though. Will add a comment about this update too

If you create a view that just returns one of the queries, not the union, does that work? Trying to determine if views have a column limit of their own.

So seeing that it looks like this is a bug I would suggest investigating at the information_schema level for those views, more specifically on the table columns for them. Given your two views have 1029 columns each it shouldn't error out on that. Try checking the count of columns rows on information schema for those views, I would also suggesting checking on the count of columns for all tables involved and see if in any of these combinations it goes over 4096.

Silly question though, why do you need this third view viewX to be a union of the two other views if its query a single column for each? Why not use the specific table that owns those columns?

@Barmar _" The server creates temporary tables under conditions such as these:
Evaluation of UNION statements, with some exceptions described later.

Evaluation of some views, such those that use the TEMPTABLE algorithm, UNION, or aggregation. "_ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html


I'm saying that the view is creating a temp table, which is why the query doesn't cause the error when it's not used in a view. If the temp table storage engine is InnoDB, and InnoDB has a limit of 1017 columns, then you can't have such a wide temp table.

@BillKarwin Right. The relevant setting is internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html#internal-temporary-tables-engines. Also internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine

@BillKarwin If the view is creating a temp table, then why it didn't errored for viewA or viewB. They too had 1029 columns each which is more than 1017 of innodb. Why the innodb error comes for ViewX only when I UNION. That's the part that is weird to me.

Not all views create temp tables, but use of UNION in a view would. I recommend you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-algorithms.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-table-optimization.html

@BillKarwin Thanks! That answered me. Really appreciate your time and knowledge Bill, you're awesome!
